# difference between size() and image matrix rowsxcolumns

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a beginnner in opencv. I am trying to reshape a matrix but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Mat image=imread("xyz.png",1);
cout<<image.size()<<endl;
cout<<image.rows<<"x"<<image.cols<<endl;
```

Why are these two outputs different?

Comment: What output do you get for each ?

Comment: for first case i get [180x200] and in second case 200x180

Answer (score 1):

From the [cv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-size):

> The method returns a matrix size: Size(cols, rows) . When the matrix is more than 2-dimensional, the returned size is (-1, -1).

Thus when you print the size you get `cols x rows` and in your second `cout` you get `rows x cols`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-size):

> Mat::size
> Returns a matrix size.
>
> C++: `Size Mat::size() const`
> The method returns a matrix size: Size(cols, rows) . When the matrix is more than >2-dimensional, the returned size is (-1, -1).

So in the first case you are printing cols x rows and in the second case rows x cols.